Does Masstransit supports Transactional outbox pattern in .Net 5?
I want to know that does Masstransit supports transactional outbox pattern in .Net 5 or not?
i asked chat gpt but it introduced me some fake packages that i couldn't find on nuget.org
and i followed the documentation of Masstransit
but the methods were not detected

.NET 5 has been past end of life for years now. In fact, .NET 6 reaches end of life this week.
